# Eliminar índices en dataframe vacío

Tags: datetime

estoy generando un índice de fechas para crear un dataframe. Lo que primero hago es generar el índice mediante:

```
inicio_horario = datetime(2010, 8, 1)
final_horario = datetime(2017, 12, calendar.monthlen(2017, 12))
indice_horario = pd.DatetimeIndex(start = inicio_horario, end = final_horario, freq = '12M', name = 'febreros')
```

el problema es que me crea sólo:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2010-02-28', '2011-02-28', '2012-02-29', '2013-02-28',
               '2014-02-28', '2015-02-28', '2016-02-29', '2017-02-28'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='febreros', freq='12M')
```

mientras que lo que necesitaba era todos los días de febrero solamente desde el año 2010 al 2017, o sea que el índice tendría que tener 226 de longitud.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que saltee el resto de los meses puesto que si hago frecuencia de un día va a darme el resto de los días?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Arreglado:
Generé el índice de por ejemplo 2010 al 2017 y a su vez una lista con

```
lista_anios =list(np.arrange(2010,2018,1))

inicio_medido = datetime(int(limpio_anios[0]), 1, 1)
final_medido = datetime(int(limpio_anios[len(limpio_anios)-1])+1, 1, 1,0,0)

indice = pd.DatetimeIndex(start = inicio, end = final, freq = '10min')

df_minutos_tierra = pd.DataFrame(index = indice) # data frame sólo con el índice
```

luego con un ciclo for:

```
for i in range(len(lista_anios)):
    if str(lista_anios[i]) not in limpio_anios:
        df_minutos_tierra.drop(df_minutos_tierra[str(lista_anios[i])].index, inplace = True)
```

donde

```
limpio_anios = [2011, 2014, 2016, 2017]
```

Ya está arreglado! el problema estaba en que no ponía .index para que me tomara desde el índice.

Saludos!